# How send to combobox 1 property from object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I write this combobox

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBoxRole" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"  
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Text="Choose"
    />
```

for this model

```
public class CategotyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string id;
    private string name;

    public string Id
    {
        get => id;
        private set
        {
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        private set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
 }
```

for Item source create this property

```
public IList<CategotyModel> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            var categoriesDTO = _categoryManager.GetAllCategories();
            this.categories = mapper.DefaultContext.Mapper.Map<IList<CategotyModel>>(categoriesDTO);
            return categories;
        }
    }
```

it work fun, but I don't know how sent to combo just 1 parametre , because I take `"AppStore.WPF.MVVMLight.Models.CategotyModel"` object.

Note: I take the result from server. it's never mind.

(without foreach the `IList<CategoryModel>` and write to list of the string - i think it's bad way).

**Edit**

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBoxRole" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Name" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"  
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
    Text="Choose"
    />
```

Comment: Are you saying you just want the combobox to show the Name properties of the categories? Add `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` to your ComboBox

Comment: Right, I forgot something: Add `SelectedValuePath="Name"` as well.

Comment: send the object `aplicationModel`  `categoryName = "AppStore.WPF.MVVMLight.Models.CategotyModel"`, but now the field name (applicationModel is null as shuold be)

Comment: it help, but work uncorrectly, into `ApplicationModel.CategoryName` send the object, and I have the field name in ApplicationModel, and it write the data into this field Name which you write for me. You right understand, I need send to combobox just Name From `CategoryModel` and when i choose Category send it to `ApplicationModel.CategoryName` - **edit**

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're telling me. Did you put `SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"` both on your combobox?

Comment: sorry, it my mistake, I try to explain better. I write `SelectedValuePath=name` and `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`, in UI it work (show just the `CategoryModel.Name` without id), but in viewmodel it doesn't work, because the field `SelectedItem="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}"` , take the object of the CategoryModel,  but should take the `string Category.Name` and write it to property `ApplicationModel.CategoryName`

Comment: Please show the XAML the way it is now, in your question

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be asleep today. I forgot to mention that when you're using `SelectedValuePath` you should bind SelectedValue, not SelectedItem: `SelectedValue="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}"`

Comment: can you write it by answer, it work and help me. I mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix a few things in your ComboBox: To display the Name properties of the items, add `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`. To select just the name property of the selected item instead of the whole object, add `SelectedValuePath="Name"`, and bind `ApplicationModel.CategoryName` to `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`. 
`SelectedItem` will still be the whole object, even when `SelectedValuePath` is in use.

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBoxRole" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Name" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"  
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
    Text="Choose"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you want DisplayMemberPath="Name"

```
    <ComboBox 
        x:Name="ComboBoxRole" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding ApplicationModel.CategoryName}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"  
        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
        Text="Choose"/>
```